# How to wrap divs in between an if elseif statement in PHP for Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This is my first shot at creating a combination filter based on David DeSandro's Isotope. I created this function based on an already existing implementation of the Isotope filter on my Website. What it does is outputs WordPress categories and implements them as Isotope filters. As of right now everything works very well. What I am trying to do is style each if elseif statement into its own column after it extracts the data. For example:

```
**<div class="column"><--I would like to add a div like this here**

    elseif (cat_is_ancestor_of(156, $filtered)) {
        $option .= '<li class="child-style" data-link="'.$filtered->slug.'">';
        $option .= '<a href="" title="'.$filtered->slug.'">';
        $option .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        $option .= $filtered->name;
        $option .= '</a></li>';
   }

**</div><--and here**
```

Below is the beginning of my function that I have written to accomplish this. As of now it works, but it outputs the data (in this case categories & child categories) in a neat single column list. I would ultimately like to style this list of categories so that each parent is in it's own column.

This is where I am running into difficulty as I can't seem to find a way to separate the if, elseif statements with div's without getting this error: 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF) in /Users/djmorigeau/localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/skittles-child/functions.php on line 89`. This is the error that I receive when I wrap each if, elseif statement with `<div class="col_3">code</div>` Any ideas on how I can group the results into columns?

```
function color_filter($categories, $type = 'blog') {

    $catArgs = array(
    'type'                     => 'post',
    'child_of'                 => 0,
    'parent'                   => '',
    'orderby'                  => 'name',
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'               => 1,
    'hierarchical'             => 1,
    'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
    'pad_counts'               => false );


    $catList = get_categories($catArgs);

    if(isset($categories[0])) {
        $categories = unserialize($categories[0]);

        if (function_exists('color_filter')) {

        $option = '<div class="megamenu_container megamenu_dark_bar megamenu_dark"><ul class="megamenu">';
        $option .= '<li><a class="megamenu_drop" href="#">Filter<em class="dropdown-arrow"></em></a>';
        $option .= '<div class="dropdown_fullwidth"><div class="mpcth-'.$type.'-categories mpcth-filterable-categories">';
        $option .= '<ul>';
        $option .= '<li class="active" data-link="post"><a href="#">'.__('All', 'mpcth').'</a></li>';

            foreach ($catList as $filtered) {

                if((isset($categories[$filtered->slug]) && $categories[$filtered->slug] == 'on') || !isset($categories[$filtered->slug])) {

                    if (cat_is_ancestor_of(37, $filtered)) {
                    $option .= '<li class="child-style" data-link="'.$filtered->slug.'">';
                    $option .= '<a href="" title="'.$filtered->slug.'">';
                    $option .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                    $option .= $filtered->name;
                    $option .= '</a></li>';
                    }

                    elseif (cat_is_ancestor_of(156, $filtered)) {
                    $option .= '<li class="child-style" data-link="'.$filtered->slug.'">';
                    $option .= '<a href="" title="'.$filtered->slug.'">';
                    $option .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                    $option .= $filtered->name;
                    $option .= '</a></li>';
                    }

                    elseif (cat_is_ancestor_of(176, $filtered)) {
                    $option .= '<li class="child-style" data-link="'.$filtered->slug.'">';
                    $option .= '<a href="" title="'.$filtered->slug.'">';
                    $option .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                    $option .= $filtered->name;
                    $option .= '</a></li>';
                    }

                    elseif (cat_is_ancestor_of(188, $filtered)) {
                    $option .= '<li class="child-style" data-link="'.$filtered->slug.'">';
                    $option .= '<a href="" title="'.$filtered->slug.'">';
                    $option .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                    $option .= $filtered->name;
                    $option .= '</a></li>';
                    }

                    else {
                    $option .= '<li data-link="'.$filtered->slug.'">';
                    $option .= '<a href="" title="'.$filtered->slug.'">'.$filtered->name.'</a></li>';
                    }
                }
            }
                $option .= '</ul></div></div></li></ul></div>';
                echo $option; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
elseif(...) {

     $option .= '<div class="column">';

     // your code

     $option .= '</div>';

}
```

or you mean this:

```
$done = false;

$option .= '<div class="column">';
if (cat_is_ancestor_of(37, $filtered)) {
    // your code
    $done = true;
}
$option .= '</div>';

$option .= '<div class="column">';
if (!$done && cat_is_ancestor_of(156, $filtered)) {
    // your code
    $done = true;
}
$option .= '</div>';

$option .= '<div class="column">';
if (!$done && cat_is_ancestor_of(176, $filtered)) {
    // your code
    $done = true;
}
$option .= '</div>';

$option .= '<div class="column">';
if (!$done && cat_is_ancestor_of(188, $filtered)) {
    // your code
    $done = true;
}
$option .= '</div>';

$option .= '<div class="column">';
if (!$done) {
    // your code
}
$option .= '</div>';
```